# C++ - Symbols no found when building with eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

I am trying to use the Eigen library. But when I try to compile under OSX Mavericks using XCode I get the following error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "buildProblem(std::__1::vector<Eigen::Triplet<double, int>,  std::__1::allocator<Eigen::Triplet<double, int> > >&, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>&, int)", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
  "saveAsBitmap(Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const&, int, char const*)", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What can be wrong with my code or settings? Here you can see my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include </usr/local/include/Eigen/Eigen/Sparse>
#include <vector>


typedef Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> SpMat; // declares a column-major sparse matrix type of double
typedef Eigen::Triplet<double> T;
void buildProblem(std::vector<T>& coefficients, Eigen::VectorXd& b, int n);
void saveAsBitmap(const Eigen::VectorXd& x, int n, const char* filename);



int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int n = 300;  // size of the image
   int m = n*n;  // number of unknows (=number of pixels)
    // Assembly:
    std::vector<T> coefficients;            // list of non-zeros coefficients
    Eigen::VectorXd b(m);                   // the right hand side-vector resulting from the constraints
    buildProblem(coefficients, b, n);
    SpMat A(m,m);
    A.setFromTriplets(coefficients.begin(), coefficients.end());
    // Solving:
    Eigen::SimplicialCholesky<SpMat> chol(A);  // performs a Cholesky factorization of A
    Eigen::VectorXd x = chol.solve(b);         // use the factorization to solve for the given right hand side
    // Export the result to a file:
    saveAsBitmap(x, n, argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where do you define (fucntion defintion / content) `buildProblem` amd `saveAsBitmap`? The linker seems to be unable to find those defintions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include your header files that have definitions for the saveAsBitmap and buildProblem functions.

Comment: Usually, headers are used to DECLARE functions (which has already been done in the translation unit that is shown). Definitions normally reside in `.cc`/`.cpp` or whatever named source files which must be compiled and linked against.

Comment: @Pixelchemist This is true but in smaller projects like the one above which appears to essentially be a script to perform some library operations on a matrix and then output the file it's probably easier to either a) include the function definitions in the file itself or b) include them in a header since it's 1 less thing to link to. I am aware it's bad code form but I for one am definitely guilty if the project is small.

Comment: Yeah but in this case, 1. the definitions would probably be in that translation unit instead of a header and 2. there would be no need to declare those functions since including the header would provide declarations.

Answer (score 2):

The missing functions `saveAsBitmap()`, `buildProblem()`, and other definitions required to compile that example code are posted in [this link](https://github.com/iNiKe/eigen/blob/master/doc/special_examples/Tutorial_sparse_example_details.cpp).

The `CMakeLists.txt` file is located [one directory above](https://github.com/iNiKe/eigen/tree/master/doc/special_examples) in the same repository. I had to add a line `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)` in that file and
remove the line `add_dependencies(all_examples Tutorial_sparse_example)` to compile the code, which now works just fine.